# Using '\n' instead of endl affects output, why?

Tags: c++, newline, line-breaks, flush, endl

So I made an uninitialized array in C++ and tried printing the last element to see what the output would be. Every element in an uninitialized array should have the value of 0 (right?), but the output I got was something else. This is what the main function looked like:

```
int main() {
    int i[5];
    cout << i[4] << '\n';
}
```

Running this outputs `1606416656` (same number every time) with a line break. However, changing `'\n'` to `endl` changes the output to `0` with a line break.

Why is that?

Also, trying to print `i[3]` instead of `i[4]` correctly outputs `0` even with `'\n'`. Why?

I did some research and read somewhere that `'\n'` doesn't "flush the buffer" while `endl` does. What does this "flushing the stream" actually mean, and is this what's affecting the output?

Comment: Read this article http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#endl-vs-slash-n

Comment: `int i[5]={};` will initialize your elements to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that an newly created array on the stack is initialized with zero does not hold. Therefore your output is random. Changing the program reorders the memory layout and so you see different results.

```
int main() {
    int i[5];
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; ++k)
        i[k] = 0;
    cout << i[4] << '\n';
}
```

should give you always the expected result regardless of using '\n' or endl

Answer (score 2):

> Every element in an uninitialized array should have the value of 0 (right?)

No, they have an indeterminate value. Using the values gives undefined behaviour, which is why you get unpredictable output.

> What does this "flushing the stream" actually mean, and is this what's affecting the output?

When you write to the stream, the output is stored in a memory buffer, and not necessarily sent to the final destination (the console, or a file, or whatever) straight away; this can give a large performance benefit, but can also mean that you don't see the final output when you want to. Flushing the stream pushes the data you've written to the final destination.

Comment: "to the final destination": not quite.  It pushes the data to the OS; most OS's also have internal buffering: the OS will (or should) make it look like the data was pushed to the final destination to other programs on the same machine, but if the system crashes, you still have no guarantee that the information has arrived at the final destination.

Answer (score 1):

Your array remains uninitalized. Whatever value you get is coincidental. std::endl puts newline character and flushes the output stream buffer. That is the difference of std::endl manipulator and printing just a newline character.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (although it didn't quite give an explanation to my main question). I now realize that the elements in an uninitialized array are coincidental and not necessarily just 0's.

Comment: @zenith Well, flushing the buffer is additional task done by std::endl. This means, whatever you push thoruh for printing to std::cout that remains buffered until full. Flushing makes the actual print to happen.

Comment: You're right, but flushing is not what changed the output from `1606416656` to `0` in my program.

Comment: @zecith Yes, but contents are unpredictable because of the uninitialized contents, so contents may vary.